# Only apply a Bootstrap 'Col' to a tablet size device

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an issue I can seem to get a grip of.

On my website I have 2 'Cols' (`col-md-9` and `col-md-3`) this then on the web puts them side by side (which is fine).

The right hand side (`col-md-3`) contains 3 panels in it which run underneath each other.

On a tablet size device, I have made it (`col-sm-12` and `col-sm-12`) which puts the right hand column at the bottom which I want.

and I have added `col-sm-4` to each panel so instead of running underneath each other they run side by side on the tablet.

BUT what I want to know is, is there a way of only using the `col-sm-4` when tablet size otherwise don't apply a 'col'?

I've tried using adding the `col-md-12` to the panels but this shrinks them and makes them look odd.

This is a hard thing to explain.

Bottomline is, if small, apply the 'col' otherwise don't.

Comment: Can you share your code in a fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve it I removed the col from my controlling DIV and added the sizes to each panel